# How to use .NET framework dll's as dependencies for a .NET 6.0 dll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-6.0

I am currently trying to port a .NET framework application to .NET 6.0.
I have a set of 3rd party .NET framework 4.5.2 dll's that will not be ported to .NET or .NET standard anytime soon.
The application is Windows only and is build with the `net6.0-windows` sdk.

If I use framework dll's directly from the application everything works as expected, but if I only use the framework dll's from a 6.0 dll and not from the main application I get a `MissingMethodException`.

The .NET 6.0 dll also uses the `net6.0-windows` sdk.

[image: Illustration of the scenario]

Comment: Why are you trying to use a .net framework library on .net core?

Comment: I'm honestly surprised to hear the first method works.  This is not advisable, even if it does seem to work.

Comment: I'm trying to use .net framework libraries because I have no other choice if I want to update to .NET in the next few years. It should work acording to Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#net-framework-compatibility-mode

Comment: That is fascinating, I never knew that was there.  Unfortunately that also means I have no experience with it.  I hope someone can help you.

Comment: Can you please post the full error?

Comment: Well I just tested to create a DLL from a .NET Framework lib imported in a .NET Core lib used in another .NET Core project and it work. Your problem may be because some .NET Framework DLL dependencies are missings in the Core Lib project.

Comment: More information on the `MissingMethodException` would help. The Microsoft article says this does not work for all APIs.

Comment: System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void LibraryNamespace.LibraryName.MethodName()'.'

Comment: Your best/shortest path is going to be to replace that third party library.  And redacting the useful parts of an error message isn't going to get you much help here.  Is that method a system method or from the library you are trying to reference?

Comment: @Betabot have you checked that the .NET 6 DLL is compiled against used .NET Framework lib version? Such exceptions usually mean that there is a version mismatch.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I redacted the name of the method because it's not from a publicly available library. The methods its trying to load is from the library.

Comment: @GuruStron What to use mean with compiling the .NET 6 dll agains .NET framework? Why would multitargeting the dll help?

Comment: @Betabot no, I don't mean multitargeting. I mean that this error can show that the App has reference to newer/older version of Framework DLL than .NET one.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try to identify the dependencies with the .NET framework dll which causes the failure and try to load manually in the .net 6.0 app context:

```
        try
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(DotNetframeworkDllname);
            var types = assembly.GetTypes();
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```